# auto-save-visited-interval not save automatically

Tags: emacs

I enabled the `auto-save-visited-mode` in global scope and write such a script

```
~/D/O/ORG/pySrc [undefined] λ cat sicp.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def remainder(x, y):
    return x % y


def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        retunr a
    else:
        return gcd(b, remainder(a, b))

print(gcd(30, 15))
```

Run it but find typo-error of retunr, and corrected it immediately.

The `auto-save-visited-interval` set as default 5, so I count to 10 and run it again

get error

```
  File "sicp.py", line 9
    retunr a
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the file was not saved automatically.

Consult with [auto save file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Files.html#Auto-Save-Files), which state that files will be saved in place.

What's the problem with my usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[doom-emacs issue](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/2305#issuecomment-570767778)

To enable a minor mode you must call its function: (auto-save-visited-mode +1). Setting the auto-save-visited-mode variable is not enough.

Try adding this to your config.el:

```
 (auto-save-visited-mode +1)
```

Comment: "+" in "+1" is optional, you can just put "1" which is "+1" by default.